# subtract times to find duration

Tags: python, pandas

```
idata_df['Total Time'] = (data_df['finsihed']).astype(int) - (data_df['Commencement Time']).astype(int)
```

that returns value error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 8 Feb 2016  10:31'`

the value types for both are object.

what is the simplest way of getting the duration between commencement Time and finished?

Comment: Have you looked at `strptime`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, you will be able to calculate time differences once you have datetime values. Currently they are strings, hence the advice to use `strptime`, or preferably [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strptime` to parse time formats:

```
from datetime import datetime
FMT = "%d %b %Y  %H:%M"
start = datetime.strptime(data_df['Commencement Time'], FMT)
stop = datetime.strptime(data_df['finished'], FMT)
total_time = (stop - start).total_seconds()
```

Note: `total_seconds()` returns a float, so you'll want to convert it to an integer if that is not acceptable for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([[' 8 Feb 2016  10:31', ' 8 Feb 2016  12:31', ' 8 Feb 2016  17:31'],
                  [' 10 Feb 2016  10:31', ' 11 Feb 2016  12:31', ' 13 Feb 2016  12:31']]), columns=['Start','Stop'])
print(df)

                Start                 Stop
0   8 Feb 2016  10:31   10 Feb 2016  10:31
1   8 Feb 2016  12:31   11 Feb 2016  12:31
2   8 Feb 2016  17:31   13 Feb 2016  12:31
```

You need to convert these to a `dtype` of `datetime` since they currently are `object` (use `df.dtypes` to check this).

You can do it explicitly:

```
df.Start = pd.to_datetime(df.Start)
df.Stop = pd.to_datetime(df.Stop)
```

or using apply:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
```

Now the difference works:

```
df['Total Time'] = df.Stop - df.Start

print(df)

  Start               Stop       Total Time
0 2016-02-08 10:31:00 2016-02-10 10:31:00 2 days 00:00:00
1 2016-02-08 12:31:00 2016-02-11 12:31:00 3 days 00:00:00
2 2016-02-08 17:31:00 2016-02-13 12:31:00 4 days 19:00:00
```